# Xcode - The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without AppMeasurement

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, admob

I know this question has been asked several times, but none of the answers I've read online have actually solved my problem.
I explain the problem:
I update my iOS apps (made with Unity) monthly, I've never had any kind of problem until about a week ago when I get this error when I try to launch the app:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without AppMeasurement. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to include the AppMeasurement framework and set the -ObjC linker flag. Google Ad Manager publishers, follow instructions here: [https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist'](https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist%27)
> *** First throw call stack:
> (0x18ed1c870 0x187087c00 0x18eda14f8 0x10e9ac4a0 0x10e9ac614 0x196beb6a8 0x196bed300 0x196bf044c 0x196bfebe4 0x196bff3ec 0x1f8625928 0x1f8625a04)
> -> applicationDidBecomeActive()
> libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

I tried the application on both iPhone and iPad and the error is always the same. I've been following the same steps for about a year and I've never had any kind of problem with it. Could it be a bug in Google's SDKs?

**I don't use cocoapods** as the application build is on a Windows system, so I export the xcode project which is passed onto my macbook, then adding the packages via links manually.
The packages included are:

- https://github.com/googleads/swift-package-manager-google-mobile-ads.git
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

As usual I added the packages in the framework, then I deactivated the Bitcode from the build settings and finally in the info.plist file I added the key "**GADIsAdManagerApp**" - "Bool" "True"

These have been the steps taken for months without any kind of problem, for about a week I have been receiving the error written above. Anyone getting the same error? Has any procedure changed with the new versions of the SDKs?

I'm also adding the currently downloaded versions of the AdMob and Firebase SDKs.

- -GoogleMobileAds 10.13.0
- -Firebase 10.17.0
- -GoogleAppMeasurement 10.17.0

Thanks everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue.

Seems like there's a bug maybe in the SDK.

1. Try selecting `Up to Next Minor Version` under `Dependency Rule` in Swift Packages.
2. Then, right-click on `Package dependencies` in the right pane and select `Update to Latest Package Versions`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! For anyone having the same problem, simply install version 10.6 of the Firebase package and everything will work fine.